# Access a function in child page within a frame from the MainPage

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

I'm trying to access a function or the UI components in a .XAML page that is loaded into a frame.
In my MainPage I have a frame that is used to display different pages using...

```
Frame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(View::typeid));
```

I can access functions within the MainPage from the View page using...

```
View::View() : rootPage(MainPage::Current)
{
...
}
View::onClickBtnAdd(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
 rootPage->ResetImageView();
}
void View::DoSomething(){
//do some stuff in the View page
}
```

This allows functions within MainPage.xaml.cpp to be accessed from View.xaml.cpp and works fine.
I want to be able to access View.xaml.cpp from MainPage.xaml.cpp... something like the following.

```
MainPage::onImageTapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
View->DoSomething();
}
```

I've had a look at the documentation for [Frame Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame) and it looks like SourcePageType is what I might need but I can't figure out how to use it.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast Frame->Content in your MainPage to your View type, and that should give you access to its public methods.

Comment: Argh I was so close at one point... I had View^ V = (View^)Frame->Content->GetType();I just had to get rid of the ->GetType(), that was throwing me off!

Comment: It's always the small things that trip us up. :) Glad that helped.